# Populating row of dates depending on month picked

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet where the user is supposed to pick a Month-Year from a dropdown in one cell A2. I have a formula I found that populates the row depending on the year and month picked but I am wondering if it's possible to dynamically delete the columns when a day(specifically the 31st, or 29th-31st this february) doesnt exist for a specific month. For example, April 31 - Column AF exists but the cell for date is blank because that date doesnt exist. I am asking this because I have a Total Column that I want as my last column after the last day for each month.

The Formula I used to populate the rows is:

```
=TRANSPOSE(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ArrayFormula(date($A$1,month(A2&1),1)+transpose(COLUMN($C$1:$AV$1)-3)),day(EOMONTH(date($A$1,month(A2&1),1),0)),1))
```

Here is a shared google sheet of my sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m2vWg37PeMFTZj8QeWL0oIMBc4WT1FjFuapLTERMjGQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete range B2:AJ3 and use in B2:

```
=INDEX({TEXT(SEQUENCE(1, DAY(EOMONTH(A2&"/"&A1, 0)), A2&"/"&A1, 1), 
 {"d"; "ddd"}), {"Total"; ""}})
```

[image]

Comment: This combines the two formulas from the previous responses into just one formula in one cell. Will definitely be using this in many more projects in the future, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just clear cells `$B2:$AF2` and in cell `C3` place

```
=ArrayFormula(IF($B2:$AF2="",,TEXT($B2:$AF2,"ddd")))
```

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`TEXT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139)

Comment: thank you very much for the code! It helped in a way that the days that doesnt exist will have blank entry for the day of the week. Is there any way that the column be deleted entirely for those dates that dont exist?

Comment: No. Because those last columns `AD-AF` act as "placeholders" for the dates `29-31`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to remove empty spaces in your dates:

```
=transpose({ARRAYFORMULA(DATE(A1,MONTH(A2&1),ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A" & DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(A1, MONTH(A2&1), 1), 0))))));"Total"})
```

It appends "Total" at the end of the range returned by the arrayformula().
Then you can combine this with @marikamitsos formula

**Sample:**

[image]